# make java plugin use the browser certificates

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a java applet that communicates with a spring application running on tomcat and using spring's http invoker.

We want to secure the applet using ssl with client authentication, we have a jsp page for login, after successful login the applet loads.

The jsp page is secured with ssl, when the applet loads the http invoker inside the applet is doing a second handshake apparently not related to the browser handshake, OK, I don't mind that, but I want the java plugin to use browser certificates and client certificates but its not, I have to load the client certificate to the java plugin also using the java ControlPanel, and if my server's certificate is self signed then I have to load the server certificate also to the java ControlPanel and to the nrowser.

Another thing is when the applet starts loading the java plugin pops a dialog asking for the client keystore password, I would like to avoid that.

So to conclude: I would like the java plugin to use the browser's trusted certificates and client certificates, and to avoid the keystore password dialog that pops up.

I have googled for it for two days and can't find any clue of how to accomplish that.

I will appreciate any help.

I'm using jdk 1.6.0 u23 and firefox 3.6.13.

Answer (score 1):

Java has its own `keystore` database which holds these client certificates, this is controlled by 3 variables;

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=<client_keystore_file_path>
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<password to access the client keystore file>
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=<keystore_type>
```

for example;

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=c:\certs\client.pfx
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=test
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
```

To be able to use this, you have to use `keytool` program (that comes with JRE/JDK) to convert & add client certificates into the keystore, [`here`](http://2muchtea.wordpress.com/2008/12/28/creating-a-keystore-using-keytool-from-java/) is an example on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually I have some experience with java ssl, but this is not an option in an applet since unsigned applets are limited in their ability to access system properties and file system. the only way unsigned applets can use ssl is through the plugin http connection provider and keystore that was setup with the java ControlPanel , or use browser keystore. we accomplished it with keystore in the java plugin ControlPanel but not with browser keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Java plugin documentation says its possible to applets access the browser keystore:

http://www.java.net/external?url=http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/keystores.html

But unfortunaly, the docs are sparse and I never tried to do that.

Good luck and post your solution here if you find it!